# find the optimal matching number of characters between two strings (something like string alignment but not in some ways)

Tags: python, string, match

I am trying to do this in Python. 
I have two sequences:

seq1:  'A B C D E'

seq2:  'A R C B E'

Suppose I want to "count" the number of characters in both seq1 and seq2
but in the following way, suppose I draw a line from A in seq1 to A in seq2 and likewise connect C--C and E--E  but if I connect B--B this connecting line will CROSS the line linking C--C so ...
I want to count EITHER  B---B     OR C--C and NOT BOTH since their lines cross and find the total number of such connections I can make between two strings.

Is there a way to do this? I am sure what I am trying to do has a name but I don't know it and that makes searching online about possible methods difficult too.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Sounds like a typical homework question!

Comment: Are elements in sequences unique?

Comment: Yes the elements of the two strings are unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sound like the [longest common subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) problem. A simplified version of the dynamic programming algorithm for Levenshtein distance solves this.

There's a host of [Python implementations of LCS](https://www.google.com/search?q=longest%20common%20subsequence%20python) on the interwebs. The pseudocode that the Wikipedia gives is also trivial to translate to Python.